# Speaker Recognition TypeError: Input 'filename' of 'ReadFile' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of string

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am running this code from the tutorial here:
https://keras.io/examples/audio/speaker_recognition_using_cnn/
with a custom dataset, that is divided in 2 datasets as in the tutorial. However, I got this error:

```
TypeError: Input 'filename' of 'ReadFile' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of string.
```

[image]
col lab link https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bBplixcAu6iCMfQ4njNeByozjet3GkNf#scrollTo=5SGb0kVC3JGW

code

```
def paths_and_labels_to_dataset(audio_paths, labels):
    """Constructs a dataset of audios and labels."""
    path_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(audio_paths)
    audio_ds = path_ds.map(lambda x: path_to_audio(x))
    label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(labels)
    return tf.data.Dataset.zip((audio_ds, label_ds))


def path_to_audio(path):
    """Reads and decodes an audio file."""
    audio = tf.io.read_file(path)
    audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(audio, 1, SAMPLING_RATE)
    return audio


def add_noise(audio, noises=None, scale=0.5):
    if noises is not None:
        # Create a random tensor of the same size as audio ranging from
        # 0 to the number of noise stream samples that we have.
        tf_rnd = tf.random.uniform(
            (tf.shape(audio)[0],), 0, noises.shape[0], dtype=tf.int32
        )
        noise = tf.gather(noises, tf_rnd, axis=0)

        # Get the amplitude proportion between the audio and the noise
        prop = tf.math.reduce_max(audio, axis=1) / tf.math.reduce_max(noise, axis=1)
        prop = tf.repeat(tf.expand_dims(prop, axis=1), tf.shape(audio)[1], axis=1)

        # Adding the rescaled noise to audio
        audio = audio + noise * prop * scale

    return audio


def audio_to_fft(audio):
    # Since tf.signal.fft applies FFT on the innermost dimension,
    # we need to squeeze the dimensions and then expand them again
    # after FFT
    audio = tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)
    fft = tf.signal.fft(
        tf.cast(tf.complex(real=audio, imag=tf.zeros_like(audio)), tf.complex64)
    )
    fft = tf.expand_dims(fft, axis=-1)

    # Return the absolute value of the first half of the FFT
    # which represents the positive frequencies
    return tf.math.abs(fft[:, : (audio.shape[1] // 2), :])


# Get the list of audio file paths along with their corresponding labels

class_names = os.listdir(DATASET_AUDIO_PATH)
print("Our class names: {}".format(class_names,))

audio_paths = []
labels = []
for label, name in enumerate(class_names):
    print("Processing speaker {}".format(name,))
    dir_path = Path(DATASET_AUDIO_PATH) / name
    speaker_sample_paths = [
        os.path.join(dir_path, filepath)
        for filepath in os.listdir(dir_path)
        if filepath.endswith(".wav")
    ]
    audio_paths += speaker_sample_paths
    labels += [label] * len(speaker_sample_paths)

print(
    "Found {} files belonging to {} classes.".format(len(audio_paths), len(class_names))
)

# Shuffle
rng = np.random.RandomState(SHUFFLE_SEED)
rng.shuffle(audio_paths)
rng = np.random.RandomState(SHUFFLE_SEED)
rng.shuffle(labels)

# Split into training and validation
num_val_samples = int(VALID_SPLIT * len(audio_paths))
print("Using {} files for training.".format(len(audio_paths) - num_val_samples))
train_audio_paths = audio_paths[:-num_val_samples]
train_labels = labels[:-num_val_samples]

print("Using {} files for validation.".format(num_val_samples))
valid_audio_paths = audio_paths[-num_val_samples:]
valid_labels = labels[-num_val_samples:]

# Create 2 datasets, one for training and the other for validation
train_ds = paths_and_labels_to_dataset(train_audio_paths, train_labels)
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=BATCH_SIZE * 8, seed=SHUFFLE_SEED).batch(
    BATCH_SIZE
)

valid_ds = paths_and_labels_to_dataset(valid_audio_paths, valid_labels)
valid_ds = valid_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=32 * 8, seed=SHUFFLE_SEED).batch(32)


# Add noise to the training set
train_ds = train_ds.map(
    lambda x, y: (add_noise(x, noises, scale=SCALE), y),
    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE,
)

# Transform audio wave to the frequency domain using `audio_to_fft`
train_ds = train_ds.map(
    lambda x, y: (audio_to_fft(x), y), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE
)
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

valid_ds = valid_ds.map(
    lambda x, y: (audio_to_fft(x), y), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE
)
valid_ds = valid_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Comment: Please provide the code sniped that lead to the error

Comment: part [19] in col lab code https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/audio/ipynb/speaker_recognition_using_cnn.ipynb

Comment: Please provide the code in the question not a link and the location of the error in the code

Comment: @abdou_dev Done please Check again

Comment: Did you try this :     `audio_ds = path_ds.map(lambda x: path_to_audio(str(x)))`

Comment: @abdou_dev yes and doesnt work its something related to the type of the files but I Cant solve